# I want to reorder an array of strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, listview

I have an array of String ["a", "b", "c", "d"]. My task is to add them to a listView in order like this:

1. row ==> d
2. row ==> c d
3. row ==> b c d
4. row ==> a b c d

For now I have created an empty String and through a for loop I added an array of items to it by + but problem is if I use this method, the ListView will look like:

1. row ==> d
2. row ==> d c
3. row ==> d c b
4. row ==> d c b a

This is what I have done: 
...

```
String arrNaslovi[] = reverse.split(" ");
String deli = "";

for(int i=arrNaslovi.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    deli += arrNaslovi[i] + " ";
    arrayNaslovi.add(deli);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayNaslovi);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: just reverse once you get `d c b a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the order of the String creation:

```
deli = reverse[i] + " " +  deli;
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating the array you can use
  `Collections.reverse(arrayNaslovi);`

Answer (score 0):

Use SortedSet -- TreeSet is an implementation -- instead of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple approach like this.

```
public List<String> myList() {
    String[] a = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    //reverse the array
    String[] b = reverse(a).split("");
    String out = "";
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String aB : b) {
        out += aB;
        //reverse it back
        list1.add(reverse(out.split("")));
    }
    return list1;
}

String reverse(String[] string) {
    String out = "";
    for (int i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!string[i].isEmpty())
            out += string[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```